# Changing a string into it's number value in python. [ord()]

Tags: python

I am writing a program in python that calculates the number equivalent of a string and prints it. (By number equivalent, I mean a=1 b=2 ... so the seventh letter in the alphabet is converted to the number 7.) So if the word was *abc* then it would turn out to be 123. And if possible, the numbers (in my example *123*) are added. (So in my example the result that is printing would be 6.) I tried doing this letter by letter, using the *ord()* function. But that ended up being where you type each letter and press enter and then add spaces for empty letters. The code was meant to calculate the number value of each letter in the word, add all of the values, and tell True if the number was 100 or false if it was anything else. Here it is... `

```
#collect info
ar=raw_input('Letter')
br=raw_input('Letter')
cr=raw_input('Letter')
dr=raw_input('Letter')
er=raw_input('Letter')
fr=raw_input('Letter')
gr=raw_input('Letter')
hr=raw_input('Letter')
ir=raw_input('Letter')
jr=raw_input('Letter')
kr=raw_input('Letter')
lr=raw_input('Letter')
mr=raw_input('Letter')
nr=raw_input('Letter')
#ord it
ap=ord(ar)
bp=ord(br)
cp=ord(cr)
dp=ord(dr)
ep=ord(er)
fp=ord(fr)
gp=ord(gr)
hp=ord(hr)
ip=ord(ir)
jp=ord(jr)
kp=ord(kr)
lp=ord(lr)
mp=ord(mr)
np=ord(nr)
#sub 96
a=(ap-96)
b=(bp-96)
c=(cp-96)
d=(dp-96)
e=(ep-96)
f=(fp-96)
g=(gp-96)
h=(hp-96)
i=(ip-96)
j=(jp-96)
k=(kp-96)
l=(lp-96)
m=(mp-96)
n=(np-96)
#chk for 96
if a==-64:
    a=0
if b==-64:
    b=0
if c==-64:
    c=0
if d==-64:
    d=0
if e==-64:
    e=0
if f==-64:
    f=0
if g==-64:
    g=0
if h==-64:
    h=0
if i==-64:
    i=0
if j==-64:
    j=0
if k==-64:
    k=0
if l==-64:
    l=0
if m==-64:
    m=0
if n==-64:
    n=0

#add
value=a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n

#spit
if value==100:
    print 'True (100)'
if value<100 or value>100:
    print 'False (', value, ')'`
```

I can't figure out how to do this. So, an explanation would be nice, a full code re-write would be enjoyed, but not required.

-Adam

P.S. If there is anything I forgot to add to this question, just tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> aword="iabcdefghijklm"
>>> value=sum(map(ord,aword),(1-ord("a"))*len(aword))
>>> print value==100, value
True 100
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming everything is lowercase and input is only a-z

```
sum((ord(c) - ord('a') + 1 for c in s))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from string import lowercase,uppercase
>>> alphabet = lowercase+uppercase
>>> mapper = {c:i for i,c in enumerate(alphabet,start=1)}
>>> aword = "Letter"
>>> sum(mapper[l] for l in aword)
106
```

Create a dictionary which maps a character `c` to the position it is in the alphabet `i`. We then pass `sum` a generator expression which looks up `i` for each character in `aword`, resulting in all the character values being summed.

Comment: this handles upper and lower-case numbers differently. I'd just use `lowercase` and use 'aword.lower()` on the list comprehension...